# How can I convert four bytes of big endian binary data to IEEE floating point using C#? 

Tags: c#, binary, ieee-754

How can I convert four bytes of binary data (big endian) to an IEEE floating point value using C#?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Haji - when asking such a question, we need to understand what you have tried, where you are stuck and if possible see the relevant code. We will not write the whole code for you, but we can help with specific problems. Please add the details I asked for - in particular, what exactly do you need help with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't see why the OP should show "what have you tried" here, the question is about a specific enough detail. More specs on the data would have been nice though.

Comment: actually i want full code, or want to know any built-in function, which can do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to reverse the incoming array and give that to the .Net Framework's `BitConverter`:

```
byte[] reversed = data.Reverse().ToArray();
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(reversed, 0);
```

---

For a full-fledged bit-converter that works with big-endian values, take a look at`MiscUtil.Conversion.BigEndianBitConverter` in the [MiscUtil library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) by Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell, and then use [`ToSingle(byte[] value, int startIndex)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx):

```
byte[] data;
float value = BigEndianBitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);
```

The methods it supports are the same as those of the [`BitConverter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) in the .Net framework. The source can be found on the MiscUtil website.

Comment: Just to say; while I have made contributions to that library, most of it, including BigEndianBitConverter, is entirely Jon

Comment: The source code can be downloaded from the [MiscUtil website](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).